# FFMPEG on Android java application

Tags: java, android, cordova, video, ffmpeg

I'm prototyping a Hybrid app using Cordova: https://cordova.apache.org. Also using this plugin: https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor

The plugin renders a video into new formats using FFMPEG. The specific piece of code which does this is here:

https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor/blob/master/src/android/VideoEditor.java

```
al.add("ffmpeg");
al.add("-i");
al.add(videoSrcPath);
String[] ffmpegCommand = al.toArray(new String[al.size()]);
vk.run(ffmpegCommand, workFolder, appContext);
Log.d(TAG, Arrays.toString(ffmpegCommand));
```

When logged out in Android Studio with variables it is:

```
[ffmpeg, -y, -i, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20150709_172753.mp4, -strict, experimental, -s, 320x320, -r, 24, -vcodec, libx264, -preset, ultrafast, -b, 2097152, -ac, 1, -ar, 22050, -t, 2.0, /storage/emulated/0/Movies/HelloWorld/VID_render-1436477283566.mp4]
```

This is working perfectly.

I want to modify this command to allow multiple videos, and other options. Here is an FFMPEG terminal command i've tested on my machine working:

```
./ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -i b.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -loglevel debug -strict -2 output.mp4
```

I've attempted to modify the java code but this fails:

```
al.add("ffmpeg");
al.add("-i");
al.add(videoSrcPath); 
al.add("-i");
al.add(videoSrcPath2);
al.add("-filter_complex");
al.add("[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]");
al.add("-map");
al.add("[v]");
al.add("-map");
al.add("[a]");
al.add("-strict");
al.add("-2");
```

This is the failing command when logged out with variables:

```
[ffmpeg, -y, -i, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20150709_175137.mp4, -i, /storage/emulated/0/Movies/HelloWorld/20150709_234321.mp4, -filter_complex, [0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a], -map, [v], -map, [a], -strict, -2, experimental, -s, 320x320, -r, 24, -vcodec, libx264, -preset, ultrafast, -b, 2097152, -ac, 1, -ar, 22050, -t, 2.0, /storage/emulated/0/Movies/HelloWorld/VID_render-1436478706526.mp4]
```

I try to use the logging feature of FFMPEG, I can't get it to return back to the Java Log, which really restricts what I can debug :(

```
al.add("-loglevel");
al.add("debug");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was the working code to allow multiple videos to render using cordova-plugin-video-editor and it's dependancy library ffmpeg4android:

index.html

```
VideoEditor.transcodeVideo(
    videoTranscodeSuccess,
    videoTranscodeError,
    {
        fileUri: file.fullPath,
        fileUri2: file2.fullPath,
        outputFileName: videoFileName,
        quality: VideoEditorOptions.Quality.LOW_QUALITY,
        outputFileType: VideoEditorOptions.OutputFileType.MPEG4,
        optimizeForNetworkUse: VideoEditorOptions.OptimizeForNetworkUse.YES,
        duration: 2
    }
);
```

VideoEditor.js line 99

```
final File inFile = this.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(options.getString("fileUri"));
if (!inFile.exists()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "input file does not exist");
    callback.error("input video does not exist.");
    return;
}

final File inFile2 = this.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(options.getString("fileUri2"));
if (!inFile2.exists()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "input file2 does not exist");
    callback.error("input video2 does not exist.");
    return;
}

final String videoSrcPath = inFile.getAbsolutePath();
final String videoSrcPath2 = inFile2.getAbsolutePath();
```

VideoEditor.js line 230

```
al.add("ffmpeg");
al.add("-i"); // input file
al.add(videoSrcPath); 
al.add("-i"); // input file 2
al.add(videoSrcPath2);
al.add("-filter_complex");
al.add("[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]");
al.add("-map");
al.add("[v]");
al.add("-map");
al.add("[a]");
al.add("-strict");
al.add("-2");
al.add("-preset");
al.add("ultrafast");
al.add(outputFilePath); // output file at end of string

String[] ffmpegCommand = al.toArray(new String[al.size()]);
vk.run(ffmpegCommand, workFolder, appContext);
```

Since getting this to work, I noticed that the ffmpeg4android library requires a license:

```
I/Videokit﹕ licenseCheck in path: /data/data/com.example.hello/files
I/Videokit﹕ isLicExistsComplex...
I/Videokit﹕ trying to open /data/data/com.example.hello/files/ffmpeglicense.lic
I/Videokit﹕ license file found...
I/Videokit﹕ You used 1 of your 15 trial days.
```

The license information can be found here:

http://www.appfree.org/item.php?item_id=com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android
http://ffmpeg4android.netcompss.com/home/purchase

There is an alternate version of cordova-plugin-video-editor using the android-ffmpeg-java library here:

https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor/pull/13

Answer (score 0):

The original commandline has these options:

```
-strict, experimental
```

Your new one has this:

```
-strict, -2, experimental
```

It looks like that's what makes it break. If not, please log the stdout/stderr so you can see what it complains about.

Comment: this is needed to ensure the aac encoder is used! I've managed to get it working by removing the other attributes

Comment: There is some documentation here which helped: http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html